# Flutter SliverAppBar -- Allow scrolling until SliverAppBar is no longer visible

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

I am trying to create a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar`. Since the `SliverGrid` that contains the main content may frequently have insufficient content to allow scrolling past the 'SliverAppBar', the UI now feels 'stuck'; the user can only scroll until a part of the `SliverAppBar` but never until it is hidden.

Therefore, I'm looking for away to allow scrolling only until the `SliverAppBar` is hidden.

Below is my current code,

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            expandedHeight: 500.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset(
                'tree_logo.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),

          SliverGrid.count(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            childAspectRatio: 4 / 3,
            children: [
              PermissibleModuleCard(
                moduleTitle: 'Master Data',
                moduleDescription:
                    'Edit berbagai master-master data (client, supplier, tenaga kerja & material) serta konstanta-kosntanta lainnya (PPN, Alamat, etc.)',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the docs, I found the `center` property for `CustomScrollView`. This allowed me to set my `SliverList` as the center widget.

Final code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey _sliverKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        center: _sliverKey,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Image.asset(
              'tree_logo.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          SliverGrid.count(
            key: _sliverKey,
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            childAspectRatio: 4 / 3,
            children: [
              PermissibleModuleCard(
                moduleTitle: 'Master Data',
                moduleDescription:
                    'Edit berbagai master-master data (client, supplier, tenaga kerja & material) serta konstanta-kosntanta lainnya (PPN, Alamat, etc.)',
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return MasterDataModulesHomePage();
                  }));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me so much! I don't know why this is as hidden as it is 